# Replace black screen ubuntu with static image

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-classic.

I'd like to replace the black 'screensaver' with a static image. The closest I've been able to do is to install xscreensaver, but then the images pan around and things whilst I'd like it to be a static image. Any ideas?